# Avoid adding virtual directory to path on an ASP.NET 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On an ASP.NET 5 MVC view I have the following:

```
<header style="background-image: '/assets/poster.jpg')">
```

The folder "assets" is inside wwwroot ...

This works fine but when I host the project on the server under a virtual directory I need to add the virtual directory name to the path:

```
<header style="background-image: '/virtualdirectory/assets/poster.jpg')">
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried using '~/assets/poster.jpg'??

Comment: No I didn't ... Can I use "~" in this case? I also have problems when the same code line is inside a CSS file and in that case I cannot use ~ or can I?

Comment: @NEDian: I forgot, but yes I did use ~ in the header backgound path but in that case it does not even work on my development machine ... I don't think "~" works on client side code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly , This will work

```
<img src='~/assets/poster.jpg'/>
```

But, this won't

```
<div style="width:990px; height:99px; background-image: url('~/assets/poster.jpg')"> </div>
```

For your inline style, you can use the [Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) helper method to generate the application absolute path.

The below code should work.

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; 
            background-image:url('@Url.Content("~/assets/poster.jpg")')"></div>
```

If you want it in a css class, you can simply use the relative path.

```
.myTest {
    background-image: url('../assets/gravatar.png');
     width:100px;height: 50px;
}
```

Assuming your css file is under a directory(Ex:css) which is a sibling to `assets` folder.

Comment: What about paths in CSS files? Any suggestion in that?

Comment: @Miguel You should be able to use it in css. See my updated answer.